# Verificar se uma string esta contida em outra sem a biblioteca string.h?

Tags: c

Eu preciso verificar se uma string esta contida em outra e retorna a posição em que a primeira letra apareceu.

Eu vi aqui no site o seguinte código, porém não posso utilizar a biblioteca `string.h`.

```
include stdio.h  
include string.h

int main()   
{  
    char s1[20];  
    char s2[20];  
    printf("Digite uma string : ");  
    scanf("%s", s1);  
    printf("Digite outra string : ");  
    scanf("%s", s2);  
    printf("%ld", strstr(s1, s2) - s1);  
}
```

Eu tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

```
void str_conteudo( char str1[], char str2[])
{  
int i=0;
int y;

while(str1[i] == str2[i] && str2[i] != 0) 
{
    if (str2[i] != str1[i])
        return i;
    i++;
}

y=i;
printf("Indice do primeiro caractere que contem a string 2: %d ", y);

}
```

Mas nao esta aumentando, o q pode esta errado?

Comment: Só algumas notas: 1) se você selecionar o código e clicar no botão **`{ }`** (ou usar `Ctrl + K`), seu código ficará formatado; 2) o [pt.so] não é um fórum.

Comment: O problema em si está claro, mas você já tentou algo?

Comment: @LINQ tentei aqui mas n deu certo, eu edito o codigo e ponho o meu entao?

Comment: É, você pode [edit] a pergunta e colocar logo abaixo a sua tentativa explicando qual foi a lógica que você usou para chegar no código e qual foi o problema que enfrentou.

Comment: https://opensource.apple.com/source/tcl/tcl-10/tcl/compat/strstr.c.auto.html

Comment: @VictorStafusa é normal usar aquele "padrão" que está sendo usado nos parâmetros? Digo, de declarar os tipos abaixo e tal. Nunca tinha visto isso. Sequer sabia que era possível.

Comment: @LINQ Isso daí existe, é a forma K&R original, mas é considerado arcaico.

Answer (score 1):

Basta dar uma olhada no [código da função `strstr` e copiar e colar ele](https://opensource.apple.com/source/tcl/tcl-10/tcl/compat/strstr.c.auto.html).

Desconsiderando-se os comentários de cabeçalho e documentação, eis o código:

```
char *
strstr(string, substring)
    register char *string;  /* String to search. */
    char *substring;        /* Substring to try to find in string. */
{
    register char *a, *b;

    /* First scan quickly through the two strings looking for a
     * single-character match.  When it's found, then compare the
     * rest of the substring.
     */

    b = substring;
    if (*b == 0) {
        return string;
    }
    for ( ; *string != 0; string += 1) {
        if (*string != *b) {
            continue;
        }
        a = string;
        while (1) {
            if (*b == 0) {
                return string;
            }
            if (*a++ != *b++) {
                break;
            }
        }
        b = substring;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Há algumas coisas que podem ser alteradas, em especial a notação arcaica K&R de declarar os tipos dos parâmetros entre o `)` e o `{` ser substituída pela notação atual, o modificador `register` que pode ser ignorado em compiladores modernos e o `+= 1` que pode ser substituído por `++`, entre outras pequenas mudanças possíveis. No entanto, o código é essencialmente esse e qualquer outra coisa que você faça, supondo que esteja correta, será equivalente a isso.

Comment: Desculpa a ignorancia, mas n consegui entender e n sei como aplicaria isso no meu codigo :/, tem mtas funcoes q eu desconheco como NULL, breack...

Comment: @flavio `break` serve para interromper o `while (1)`. O `NULL` indica que a segunda string não existe dentro da primeira. `continue` serve para forçar a próxima iteração do `for`.